# Replace window.location with anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I have a select box, each row is a project. I want to click a project and redirect me to that project page. On every page I have the same select box. My select looks like this:

```
select class="select_box" name="state" style="width:200px;float:right;margin-right:45px;">
    <? for(var i=0;i<proiecte[0].length;i++){?>
    <option class="optiune" value="<?=proiecte[0][i]?>"><?=proiecte[0][i]?></option>
    <? }?>
    </select>
```

The select box looks good.

Now, my project link looks like this:

```
https://script.google.com/a/macros/COMPANY/s/AKfycbytWWGfWbOj_-Qi6eXwZraMgAS6xa0blmRfXVzLJV4/dev?page=project&projectName=Name%20Of%20Project
```

As you can see I have 2 parameters in my URL. The first one does not need to change when I select an option from the select box, but the second one has to.
Using jQuery, I succeeded in changing the project when I click on an option and redirect to that page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".select_box").change(function(){
console.log('Selected value: ' + $(this).val());
var url = "<?=getPathFromUrl(getScriptUrl());?>?page=project&projectName=";
url += encodeURIComponent($(this).val());
//window.location.replace(url);
window.location.href = url; //i tried what TeilZeitMensch suggested
});
});
```

My problem is this one. I click on one project name and i am redirected to that page WITHOUT chaning my URL. For example, i am in project1 my URL is something like this: `....projectName=project1`. I click on another project, the info from that project loads, but the URL does not change, even if i change the parameters. 
My next problem and the biggest is that i can only select one project. After i click on project2, it loads the info and the select options. But if i select project3, i get a blank page. I tried various combination of projects, always get a white page on second change.

It should be said, that I am using Google Apps Script.

EDIT: I use console.log, after I use `window.location.href = url;` and the url is correct. I only have a problem displaying it in the link bar.

EDIT2: I found the solution:
I put this in my HTML.

```
<form id="projNavForm" action="<?=getPathFromUrl(getScriptUrl());?>"       method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="project"/>
<input type="hidden" name="projectName" value="" id="projectName"/>
</form>
```

And I used this jQuery:

```
$(".select_box").change(function(){
if($(this).val() != 'None'){
  $("#projectName").val($(this).val());
  $("#projNavForm").submit();
}
```

Comment: Did you check your select box options? Does it have the project name for each option (in the newly loaded page)?

Comment: Yes it does. It's the same value that is shown.

Comment: Please post your answer in the answer field instead of adding it to the question. (Also, appscript is for Apple scripts. I changed to the correct tag)

Answer (score 0):

For a "real change" of the url, you could use:

```
window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly? doesnt the url in the browser change, or does the url change, and the program isnt working as exspected?

Comment: Sorry, for not being specific. My URL in the browser does not change, and still, after the second change i get a white page

Comment: Thats a bit strange behaviour - to change window.location.href should change the real browser path... Maybe theres something in the Google Apps Scripts, that raise another behaviour - I dont know them... So i am sorry to not help more. Have you taken a look with something like console.log(url), if the url variable really holds the value, that you exspect?

Comment: Yes. I did that and it was the correct link. I manage to solve it using a form. I will Edit the solution. Thank you.